# Joomla.submitbutton is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, articles

I have been facing a problem when I try to update the article from the frontend then it shows this error

> Joomla.submitbutton is not a function
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Here is my code

```
<div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('article.save')">
                <span class="icon-ok"></span><?php echo JText::_('JSAVE') ?>
            </button>
        </div>
```

Update


I am also facing this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Joomla.getOptions is not a function

Which if I go to the source code I find this script

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': Joomla.getOptions('csrf.token')
    }
});
```

And that script is not visible in the actual file

Comment: Is this an issue you're having with Joomla core, a 3rd party extension or your own code?

Comment: @Lodder core joomla

Comment: And are you using the latest version of Joomla?

Comment: Yes joomla version is `3.9.1`

Comment: It looks like that Joomla javascript library is not loaded somehow on the page. That's the only thing I can imagine in this case, if this is inside a core Joomla function of a core component. Thus the above mentioned functions cannot be recognized as functions. Or it could be a javascript conflict with another javascript library.

Comment: Otherwise more info needed on the problem. The html code of a button means nothing here...

Comment: The $.ajaxSetup function does not have anything to do with this problem. It's a very important security call for executing an ajax call after that function.

Comment: @Zollie. Hi.. thanks for the feedback. Can you tell me that which javascript library should I add and where to add? Because there is no proper documentation available. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I would love to give you help on this, but normally the required javascript libraries in Joomla should be loaded without any intervention. onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('article.save') should work without any problem in Joomla if there is no any major problem caused by third party extension, like templates, components or plugin/modules. So the info you provided in your question is definitely not enough to know what is the source of this problem.

Comment: What template do you use? is changing it to another template solving this problem? A lot of question should be answered first to figure out what is your real problem on your site.

Comment: @Zollie. Very very thanks for your precious time. I have found the solution. Basically I have removed the javascript code and submit the form through php code

Comment: @ZainFarooq - You're welcome. It's great that you handled that!

Comment: If your issue is resolved, you may award the green tick to the answer that you found most correct/helpful/educational (that answer can be your own).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I have removed the javascript like `onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('article.save')"` from the `form` view of `com_content` and added the necessary php code to make form submit to the right direction. Now the form is working fine

Comment: Please award the green tick to the best answer that resolved your question (this may or may not be your own answer). By accepting an answer, you mark the page as resolved and site's automated scripts will stop bumping this page for new attention.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious if you're working with a template override of the form.

Reason I'm asking is the function Joomla.submitbutton is typically added to the page by the template for the form.

Also, Joomla.getOptions is defined in core.js, which templates can avoid or block loading.

My guess is you're using a template that has decided for whatever reason to stop Joomla from loading the minimal javascript it needs, and the developer either wasn't aware of the right way to do that or didn't care about the side effects.

Pro tip: if you made the changes you mention directly to the core files, like your words implied, you have at most 6 months before an update breaks things by overwriting them. That's why template overrides exist.